How to make UI to stay on top of the main UI in Maya
I'm currently writing a script in Python and using Qt to make UI.
The issue that I'm encountering is probably trivial, but the answer available online is not helping.
I want to make the UI window of my script to stay on top of Maya main window. But when other dialogue windows appear, I want THEM to take priority. The way it is working now is that my UI covers/hides whatever dialogue that pops up.
Can anyone suggest a solution? Is there a way to set a "priority" in which the program will know that the confirmation dialogue has to go on top.
Also, the UI of my script stays open even if I hide Maya. I guess it is part of the issue that I've described above.
I need some helpful advice how to change my UI code to make the program more user friendly.
import sys
import os
import logging
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import maya.cmds as cmds
from modelCheckerExporter import MayaSceneTools

# Add the directory containing the script to the Python path
script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
if script_dir not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(script_dir)

# Change current working directory to the script's directory
os.chdir(script_dir)


class QTextEditLogger(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, log_file_path, parent=None):
        super(QTextEditLogger, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Log Output")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 850, 400)

        self.log_file_path = log_file_path

        self.text_edit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self)
        self.text_edit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.text_edit)

        self.update_timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.update_timer.timeout.connect(self.update_log_display)
        self.update_timer.start(1000)  # Update every second

    def update_log_display(self):
        with open(self.log_file_path, 'r') as log_file:
            log_data = log_file.read()
            self.text_edit.setPlainText(log_data)

class model_checker_UI(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(model_checker_UI, self).__init__()
        self.setup_ui()
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)

        self.log_window = None
        self.log_file_path = "model_checker.log"

        # Initialize logger
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        self.clear_log_handlers()
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
        file_handler = logging.FileHandler(self.log_file_path, mode='w')  # Overwrite mode
        file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        self.logger.addHandler(file_handler)

    def clear_log_handlers(self):
        if self.logger.hasHandlers():
            self.logger.handlers.clear()
    
    def setup_ui(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("WH Model Checker 3.0")
        self.setObjectName("WHModelCheckerID")
        self.setMinimumSize(265, 450)
        self.setMaximumSize(365, 450)
        self.resize(265, 450)

        self.main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.main_layout.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 5)
        self.main_layout.setSpacing(5)
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)

        self.headder_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.headder_layout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.headder_layout.setContentsMargins(3, 3, 3, 3)
        self.headder_layout.setSpacing(2)
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.headder_layout)

        self.top_title = QtWidgets.QLabel("Check for Errors:")
        self.top_title.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.title_font_A = self.top_title.font()
        self.title_font_A.setBold(True)
        self.title_font_A.setPointSize(12)
        self.top_title.setFont(self.title_font_A)
        self.headder_layout.addWidget(self.top_title)

        self.show_log_window()


def main():
    if cmds.window("WHModelCheckerID", exists=True):
        cmds.deleteUI("WHModelCheckerID", window=True)

    if cmds.windowPref("WHModelCheckerID", exists=True):
        cmds.windowPref("WHModelCheckerID", remove=True)

    global myUI
    myUI = model_checker_UI()
    myUI.show()

main()


See [ask]. Focus on single specific problem and don't ask an opinion on SO. Anyway, here's my opinion. Your UI scenario is wierd. If you don't want an always on top tool window, just let the user configure the window stack(or z-order).

WindowStaysOnTopHint is not appropriate. Try using the Qt.Tool window flag instead, but be aware that its behavior may be inconsistent across different OS and window managers.
